# How to Delete Last Word of variable in php

Tags: php

How to last word from our Variable for example

```
$name = "Salman Khan";
```

And I want ans in only because i want tp remove **n** in my string

Comment: Just to be clear, do you want to remove the last word or letter?

Comment: echo rtrim($name,"n");

Comment: What does this have to do specifically with Cake? Seems a standard PHP question.

Comment: @salman Have you got solution?

Answer (score 2):

```
$words = explode(' ',$name); // Break words into array
$noofwords = count($words); // Find out how many
unset($words[$noofwords-1]); // remove the last one (-1 because of zero-index)
$newstring = implode(' ',$words); //put back together
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$newstring = substr($name, 0, strlen($name)-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean remove the last letter?

```
echo substr($name, 0, -1);
```

Or the last word?

`echo explode(' ', $name)[0];`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo rtrim($name,"n");
```

OR

```
echo substr($name,0,-1);
```

OR

```
echo substr($name,0,strlen($name)-1);
```

**Output**

```
salman kha
```

Answer (score -3):

Try out this one.

```
$name = 'salman khan';

$length = strlen($name);

$char = $name[$length-1];

echo rtrim($name,$char);
```